# not able to add values in application without closing it after each iteration, in qtp

Tags: qtp

When we parameterize through `datatable` in qtp, how can the values keep on adding after each iteration without closing the dialog box? Also without again opening the dialog box, if we dont exit it.

I am guessing break function can do so, but can't figure out how to do it.
Please help.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, We need to use **split action**, to split the whole recorded script. So that Exit function goes to the next action. Also setting the action with iterations, to Run All Rows from Call TO Action properties. And keeping rest actions to -> run on one iteration only.